# Advanced compilation level - list of removed methods

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I've started to use closure compiler and still hittin lot's of obstacles:)
I'm looking for the option that will output the list of removed methods/properties whatnot during the optimisation done by compiler - this would help me a lot when debugging the code.

Comment: This option does not exist. "removed" methods can be dropped as dead code, or functions that are completely inlined.

Comment: too bad, I think it would be useful addition.

Comment: There are a couple of reports the compiler can produce but they aren't comprehensive.  In the end symbol removal is a little misleading as they can become unused after functions and values have been inlined and you have to decide whether to under or over report.  The source map approach is more accurate and can pin point unused code within methods.

I've also found simply examining the code with debug renaming  (--debug) and pretty printing enabled to be enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default option that lists removed symbols.

This should be possible by using a tool to highlight all of the lines that have mappings in a generated source map. Any line that has no mapping was dropped as dead code.

However I have not stumbled across a tool that would do this. It would be highly useful though and not specific to Closure-compiler.

Comment: I built a couple different versions of this over the years, but nothing sharable.  The basic information is pretty easy to generate:

Comment: I think it would make a pretty amazing npm project. It could generate html files for each of the sources referenced in the source map, and highlight any lines referenced.